# Запаздывающая отрисовка фона окна

Tags: gui, winforms

Первоначальная цель состоит в том, чтобы подсветка текста, нарисованного с помощью `DrawThemeTextEx`, не ограничивалась клиентской областью окна. 
 Сейчас оно рисуется так:

[image]

[Здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32623/Vista-Aero-ToolStrip-on-Non-Client-Area) продемонстрирован способ расширить клиентскую область на все окно. 
 Суть способа:

- При обработке сообщения `WM_NCCALCSIZE` в структуре `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS` возвращаются координаты клиентской области, скопированные из координат окна (таким образом, клиентская область займет все окно);
- В `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` передаются стандартные размеры рамки окна.

Вроде все хорошо, если бы не маленькая неприятность. При уменьшении размеров окна прозрачная рамка рисуется поверх куска фона, который еще не был затерт в `OnPaintBackground`/`OnPaint`.
Выглядит это примерно так:

[image]

При растяжении окна фон не успеваеет перерисоваться до растяжения рамки и кусок фона окна показывает то, что находится под окном:

[image]

Вроде бы эффект и несущественный, но таки неприятный. Возможно ли такое пофиксить?

Прилагаю [архив со скомпилированной демкой и исходниками](http://files.rsdn.ru/93495/AeroTest.zip).

Comment: Картинки не видно, поэтому проблема до конца не ясна.

Comment: Похоже, у меня просто хост rsdn.ru не ресолвится o_O (вобщем - локальная проблема моих ближайших DNS)
>Залил на dropbox

на winserv 2008 R2 это выглядит так: ![screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77603664/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B/hashcode.ru.1.JPG)

Comment: Да, у меня сейчас тоже не ресолвится. Залил на дропбокс: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63973281/misc/AeroTest.zip

Comment: > на winserv 2008 R2 это выглядит так
Проблема в том, как оно выглядит в процессе изменения размера окна.

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, как оно выглядит в процессе изменения размера окна.

Без `Aero` описанная проблема не воспроизводится, но Вам нужно учесть, что `Aero` пользуются не все, и вот для этих оставшихся Ваша программа будет выглядеть именно так, как на скриншоте. Эта проблема решается проверкой наличия тем и в случае их отсутствия - отрисовкой `GUI` старыми добрыми средствами `GDI`.

**По теме отрисовки рамок:** аналогичная проблема встречается и в `Win XP`, когда меняются размеры левой и верхней границы окна: можно, к примеру заглянуть в проводник `Win XP` и подергать его левую границу, увидите как прижатый к правой границе логотип Windows (как и любые другие элементы, прижатые к правой границе окна) начинает усиленно моргать.

**Решение:** на WinXP в таких случаях, в ответ на сообщение `WM_NCCALCSIZE` следует обнулить прямоугольники `Src` и `Dst` (это `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS::rgrc[1]` и `NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS::rgrc[2]`) в момент, когда `wParam` ненулевой и вернуть системе `WVR_VALIDRECTS` в качестве результата. Это предотвратит любое копирование растров в момент изменения размеров окна.

Эффект связан с таким свойством как "перенос незатронутой изменениями области окна" при изменении его размеров. Пересечение `Src` и `Dst` определяют, какую область следует копировать, не прибегая к `WM_PAINT`. После копирования областей вызывается стандартный WM_PAINT для тех областей, которые скопированы не были.

Вот как раз наложение этих двух отрисовок и дают **непрезентабельный эффект перемаргивания границ окна**.

Я в свое время пытался экспериментировать с этими прямоугольниками, но действительно, нужного эффекта добился только обнулением обоих прямоугольников и полной перерисовки окна. Это позволяет перерисовывать окно только один раз, поэтому, при наличии второго буфера, никаких дополнительных артефактов на окне не возникает.

---

Вообще, есть у меня такое предположение, что "глюк" больше связан с тем, что окно отрисовывается слишком долго. В таких ситуациях можно обработку `WM_PAINT` реализовывать в несколько подходов: запускается стейт машина, которая за несколько сообщений отрисовывает окно, пропуская между ними критически важные сообщения `GUI`.

Проблема в том, что такая машина сложно реализуется. По сути, она возможна только в случае, когда интерфейс полностью сформирован (разработка программы завершена). И не всякий `GUI` можно так "послойно" распараллелить. Ну а об `Aero` я вообще молчу - это, по сути - декоративный инструментарий, который распараллелить просто не получится, т.к. его реализация закрыта от пользователя, вклиниться в нее со своей оптимизацией не выйдет.

Comment: > Без Aero описанная проблема не воспроизводится

Проблема становится ровно в два раза менее неприятной, если можно так выразиться. При увеличении окна эффект отсутсвует. Но, например, при уменьшении по ширине, правый кусок рамки рисуется чуть правее, чем нужно. Все, что не попадает в оконный прямоугольник, не рисуется. В результате в процессе уменьшения окна рамка справа выглядит тем тоньше, чем быстрее юзер двигает мышь.

Comment: А если обнулить `Src` и `Dst`?

Comment: @mega, может, не обнулить, а расширить до всей клиентской области?

Comment: Попробуйте расширить, но я уже обозначил проблему этой операции: перемаргивание - результат **двух** подряд идущих отрисовок. И избавиться от него можно либо корректно **настроив** эти прямоугольники, либо **запретитв** первую отрисовку. Я показал как запретить.  
 --  
Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Нет, перемаргиваний никаких нет. Трюки с двойной буферизацией используются там, где нужно.
Вся отрисовка окна - это сплошная заливка прямоугольника внутри рамки.